# Tensorflow (Parsing/Lstm)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0

Hello everyone I have a small problem on one of my neural networks, I have a sequence of
X states,

I parse to get (1, 2, 3, 4, ...X) permutations.
In my state i have (21, 3) so normally (1, 63)
I transform it to ((1, 63), (2, 63), (3, 63), (X, 63)) get the batch x data

X = 8
So I get (8, [x_a:x_b], 63) and here is the problem I would like to train my network with a batch of data and not a single sample
For my lstm network entry and (None, None, 63)

Thanks in advance

"Try new fix" : remove Y reshape

BTW: Single Sample (1, N, 63) it's work one by one

[Example of model Input/Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCvKK.png)

[Bug picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzTbq.png)

I added a test model with this it still doesn't work

Case 0:

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulQ2U.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOnv.png)

Case 1:

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwBzr.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZGsB.png)

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code, you can use backticks (`) to display code if needed. I don't understand what your input data looks like. Why are you talking about permutations. Prefer editing your question to responding to comments.

Comment: Ok, I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first "Fix" I found, is to add a padding to the sequence.

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequences, **kwargs)
```

I hope to find another solution

I have the impression that it forces the use of relu as an activation function :(